# How can calculate two columns in filament

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament

Please I want calculate two columns like test_mark and exam_mark how can define the total mark in total_mark column please

Example:
Sql
Test_mark = 40 exam_mark =30 tolal_mark =test_mark + exam_mark

How can desply it in filament table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/columns/getting-started#calculated-state

> Sometimes you need to calculate the state of a column, instead of directly reading it from a database column.
>
> By passing a callback function to the `state()` method, you can customize the returned state for that column based on the $record:
>
> ```
> Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('amount_including_vat')
>   ->state(function (Model $record): float {
>     return $record->amount * (1 + $record->vat_rate);
>   })
> ```